# problem with hosting asp.net core 2.1 in plesk cpanel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, plesk

I am having asp.net core 2.1 project and your plesk supports upto only .Net framework 4.6.2. And I am not able to host my project.It always ends up with following error

HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

What I have tried:

1. In Plesk , I clicked on Hosting Settings and untick Microsoft ASP.NET so that .NET core gets No Managed Code Application Pool.
2. And then trying to test my project .. But everytime I ends you will above error.
   I am trying to do this for 3 days :)

Comment: Please refer to http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/fix-502-error-asp-net-core.aspx. It should be fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on [Plesk's Knowledge base](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000442805-ASP-NET-Core-support-in-Plesk), it'll depend on your version of Plesk - it'll require 17.8 onwards.

> ASP.NET Core 2.x
>   **In Plesk for Windows**
>
> According to release notes, ASP.NET Core 2.0 is supported since March
>   6, 2018 on Plesk Onyx 17.8 only. Check how to upgrade to the latest
>   version.
>
> It is possible to install required components with the Autoinstaller
>   (Plesk > Tools & Settings (Server) > Updates & Upgrades > Plesk
>   hosting features > .NET Core Runtime), and then upload your
>   application manually into hosting using FTP, Visual Studio and etc.
>
> As for other versions, they are not shipped with Plesk, but can be
>   used on a server with Plesk.
>
> The required version can be installed manually using the installer
>   available on .NET Core main website.
>
> After installation, version can be verified by executing the following
>   command in the Command prompt:
>
> ```
> dotnet --version
> ```
>
> **In Plesk for Linux** Download and install manually all the required packages from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux

Comment: the dotnet --version command is only available in the SDK, which is normally not needed to host and run a website :o